# Error al crear un nuevo elemento - WPF Async/Await

Tags: c#, wpf

Al ejecutar mi código obtengo el siguiente error:

> System.InvalidOperationException' in PresentationCore.dll
>
> The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this

¿Podrian ayudarme a corregir mi código?

Código simplificado *WPF*:

```
void CrearBtnNews()
{
    KinectTileButton botontest = new KinectTileButton
    {
        Style = FindResource("KinectTileButtonStyle1") as Style,
        Content = "WeB",
        Height = 265,
        Width = 450,
        Background = null,
        BorderBrush = null
    };
    botontest.Click +=
    async (o, args) =>
    {
        await Task.Run(()=> BrowserAsync());
                 
    };
}
private void BrowserAsync()
{
    Grid gridx = new Grid();////// el ERROR ocurre en esta linea ///
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(8000);
        MessageBox.Show("working 8 seg");
                  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Lo que el error está tratando de decirte es que es ilegal crear o manipular controles visuales (como `Grid`) en un thread (hilo) que no sea el thread de interfaz.

En este caso, el problema es que `Task.Run()` ejecuta el método `BrowserAsync` en un hilo diferente, por lo que no puedes ni deberías crear un `Grid` allí. De hecho, tampoco deberías ejecutar un `MessageBox.Show()` allí. Básicamente, no puedes hacer nada en ese método que envuelva acciones de interfaz.

Es difícil proponerte una solución adecuada fuera de decirte que no puedes hacer esto, porque es obvio que tu código es solo una prueba y no hace nada por ahora.

Pero si la intención es de ejecutar un trabajo largo en el método `BrowserAsync` en un hilo diferente para que la interfaz no se tranque, eso está bien. Pero tendrás que limitarte a hacer y acumular el resultado de este trabajo usando alguna estructura que no sea un control de interfaz y luego devolver este resultado al thread principal de interfaz, donde allí sí, podrás usar este resultado para hacer modificaciones a los controles de interfaz.

Por ejemplo, ajustando tu situación un poquito, digamos que al hacer el click del botón lo que deseas hacer es un cálculo largo cuyo resultado quieres asignar a un textbox.

Similar a tu código, pudieramos intentar hacer lo siguiente:

```
botontest.Click += 
    async (src, args) =>
    {
        await Task.Run(() => CalculoLargo());
    };

private void CalculoLargo() {
    Thread.Sleep(30000); // simulando un cálculo largo
    int resultado = 100;
    textbox1.Text = $"Resultado del cálculo: {resultado}"; // error!!
}
```

Pero la sentencia que intenta asignar el resultado al textbox no es legal por las razones ya mencionadas.

Mas bien, la forma correcta de efectuar el cálculo en un hilo distinto y luego asignar el resultado al textbox es de esta manera:

```
botontest.Click += 
    async (src, args) =>
    {
        int resultado = await Task.Run(() => CalculoLargo());
        textbox1.Text = $"Resultado del cálculo: {resultado}";
    };

private int CalculoLargo() {
    Thread.Sleep(30000); // simulando un cálculo largo
    return 100;
}
```

Como puedes notar, la parte costosa aún se efectúa en un hilo distinto para no trancar el hilo de interfaz. Pero al momento de tener que asignar el resultado a un control visual (textbox), hay que hacerlo en el hilo de interfaz. En este ejemplo, esto se logra haciendo esa parte *después* del `await Task.Run()`, cuando el código allí sí es ejecutado en el hilo de interfaz.

Espero que este ejemplo te deje un modelo de cómo puedes lograr tu objetivo sin recibir el error.

Comment: Hola.Gracias por responder.¿Es imposible entonces construir una UI en un hilo paralelo?.¿Como podria cargar una pagina web sin trabar la interfaz?.Muchas Gracias de nuevo.

Comment: ¿Construir una UI en un hilo paralelo? Definitivamente no puedes hacer eso. Operaciones de UI deben efectuarse en el hilo principal de interfaz. No hay otra. ¿Como podria cargar una pagina web sin trabar la interfaz? Allí entra el ejemplo que te di. La idea es que puedes separar el trabajo en 2 partes: 1) cargar el contenido de la página web en una variable string tal vez (eso sí lo puedes hacer en un hilo paralelo 2) asignar el contenido de la variable a tus componentes de interfaz (eso debe hacerse en el hilo principal)... (continuado)

Comment: Normalmente, la primera parte es la costosa, pero esa sí puedes hacer en un hilo paralelo.  Pero te diré que en realidad, probablemente ni siquiera necesitas un hilo paralelo para hacer lo que quieres. Dependiendo de la librería que usas para cargar la página web, puede que ya incluya un método async al que le puedes hacer `await` sin necesidad de hacer un `Task.Run()`. Pero no te puedo decir sin saber lo que estás usando.

Comment: Estoy usando las librerias de cefsharp. es cierto ,no bloquea la interface. En realidad estaba testeando el tema de async/await para futuros usos.Gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Solo como acotación, si puedes crear elementos de UI en hilos alternos, pero si quieres aplicarlos o de algún modo interactuar con la UI real entonces si debes hacerlo directamente sobre el hilo principal, puedes hacerlo a través del dispatcher.

Answer (score 1):

No puedes crear un objeto visual en otro hilo. Lo que si puedes hacer es llamar al hilo de la vista dentro del otro hilo para crearlo utilizando el [Dispatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) de un elemento visual del formulario o vista.

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, ()=>{
 // crear elemento aqui
   Grid g = new Grid();
});
```

Hay 2 metodos que puedes utilizar para hacer esto.

1. [Invoke](https://www.google.com.do/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjb_N_agbLTAhXDayYKHVPoAWoQFggjMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke(v%3Dvs.110).aspx&usg=AFQjCNE8yCY_USM2fSMG9uLDnRO1KAV1Yw&sig2=co9GLLU1DciIKr11FjrBEg&cad=rjt): El hilo espera a que el hilo de la vista termine de
       crear el elemento visual y continua su ejecucion.
2. [BeginInvoke](https://www.google.com.do/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjM2aTqgbLTAhWCSyYKHVtGAcYQFgghMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.windows.threading.dispatcher.begininvoke(v%3Dvs.110).aspx&usg=AFQjCNEi7hkMl7M2KE5FAPnlmXQo85WNmQ&sig2=iN16uGEiuW2hPk-XwvevXA):
       El hilo no espera al hilo de la vista a que termine. En otras
       palabras, crea el elemento visual asincronamente al hilo en ejecucion.